# Call methods in the user before Devise sign up or registers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When signing up and editing the profile, I need to call a method in my user model to enable or disable different sets of validations. Is there a way to do that without having to completely override Devise's methods for signing up and registering? I'd rather not do that.

I'm using Ruby 2.3.1, Rails 4.2, and Devise 4.1.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way might be to subclass the Devise controllers as Devise is pretty well compartmentalized to allow customization:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :some_attribute, unless: :trusted?

  def trusted?
    !!@trusted
  end

  def trusted!
    @trusted = true
  end
end
```

---

```
class MyApp::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationController
  def build_resource(hash=nil)
    self.resource = resource_class.new_with_session(hash || {}, session)
    self.resource.trusted!
  end
end
```

---

```
# config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "my_app::registrations"}
```